# React-Webpack. Update className with css-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, css-loader

As far as I understood its possible to add only one class to the element by doing `className={styles.className}` even if it's composed of many. 
So at the current moment the code uses `ternary operator` in order to render different element styles depending on the `state.cross` value.

```
export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { cross: false };

    this.showCross = this.showCross.bind(this);
    this.showLine = this.showLine.bind(this);
  }

  showCross() {
    this.setState({cross: true});
  }

  showLine() {
    this.setState({cross: false});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.showCross} onMouseLeave={this.showLine} className={styles.blockClose}>
        <a className={this.state.close ? styles.closeCross : styles.closeLine}>&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What it actually does it makes 2 lines to look like a cross after `state` has been changed and `transform` has been applied.

```
:local(.closeLine) {
  ...20px line

  &::before {
    ...equal line
  }
}

:local(.closeCross) {
  composes: closeLine;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);

  &::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

**My question is:**
Is it possible instead of conditional rendering just toggle class by doing smth like `element.classList.toggle(className)` to manage the styling of the element.

```
:local(.closeCross) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);

  &::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could do `element.classList.toggle(className)` directly in your click handler or in componentDidMount, however you'd be losing the benefits of Reacts declarative programming model, therefore taking control from React.

Comment: @riscarrott, so from you point of view it will be better to leave the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the really awesome classnames package, which allows you to easily have multiple classes. I'm not sure of your final goal, but it would be easy to do something like:

```
<a className={classNames(
    styles.closeCross, { // <-- always applied
        [styles.closeLine]: this.state.close   <-- applied only when closed
    })}
>&nbsp;</a>
```

https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames